# Switch APN and check connection status without using a timeout

Tags: android

I have a list of APNs and I want to check which APN connection is working. For that I use the class NetworkCallback

```
   class NetworkCallback extends ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback implements Registerable {
        public void register() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) AppAnchor.getContext()
                    .getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
                new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                        .build(),
                    this
            );
        }
        public void unregister() {
            logger.info("Unregister NetworkCallback");
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) AppAnchor.getContext()
                    .getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network)
        {
            logger.debug("onAvailable:"+network.toString());
            synchronized (connectionLock) {
                mIsConnected = true;
                connectionLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Network network)
        {
            logger.debug("onLost:"+network.toString());
            synchronized (connectionLock) {
                mIsConnected = false;
                connectionLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

To check if the connection works or not I call

```
    public boolean isConnected() throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (connectionLock)
        {
            connectionLock.wait(TIMEOUT_CONNECT_SEC*1000);
            return mIsConnected;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to check that no connection is established without using a Timeout?